# What is the best way to get a list of Business objects from a list of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, layers

I am using entity framework to get a `IEnumerable<CustomersEntity>`, and I need to cast this to a `IEnumerable<CustomerBO>` to display it in some view. **I know how to do cast a `IEnumerable<T1>` to a `IEnumerable<T2>`**; but in this case, who will be in charge of it ? I thought `CustomerBO` could do it, but is it correct for an object return a list of itself ? or have I to write a layer with only one function ? I am in a MVC project, so maybe the controller could be involved; but if possible I prefer to decouple it from the DAL...

Here is what I currently have:

Entity :

```
public class CustomerEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

And Business object:

```
public class CustomerBO
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    public string InvoicesNumber { get; set; }
    public string InvoicesTotalAmount { get; set; }

    public CustomerBO(CustomerEntity customer)
    {
        //Instanciate the object
    }
}
```

Note I need a one-way only process; I won't have to insert a `CustomerBO` in the database.

Comment: The consumer always takes care of the conversion. The object being consumed doesn't know how it's being consumed or who is going to consume it, and should be kept as simple as possible. That being said, your BO having a constructor receiving the entity is a valid way to do it.

Comment: I am not familiar with entity-framework, but is this framework provide things like lazy-loading (like Hibernate/JPA for Java) too ? If so you might need to think carefully about how to handle this. Personnaly I went for the same object so I don't have to duplicate things and convert them.

Comment: @Machado "The consumer always takes care of the conversion" absolutely, but I am in a MVC project, and I'lI prefer to decouple it from the DAL. Until now I worked with entities directly, or single instances of business objects; never with lists of them.

Comment: @Walfrat Yes, entity framework natively implements lazy-loading; when I wrote `List` in my question, I meant `IEnumerable`, which allow to do lazy loading efficiently. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @gobes, I'm not sure I understood correctly, then. Your Entity is on the DAL and your BO is on the MVC project ? Is this correct ?

Comment: @Machado One can say I have a kind of service layer between the DAL and the MVC, and this layer is giving me business objects.

Comment: Machado is right. Every layer works with its own data model. So the transformation should happens at those layers that need the conversion. The coupling should happens in some place whether we like or not. You have to evaluate if the benefits outweight the costs of the decoupling process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CustomerBO class should have NO reference to the EF entity. This conversion should take place in side a repository. If the business object has any reference to the entity, it is still coupled to the database, and it can be difficult to run simulations, "what-if-scenarios" ect, independent of your data if you need to.

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
     // dont forget to close your connections, which I left out...
     public CustomerBO GetCustomer(id)
     {
          return Map(DBContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id).Single());
     }

     public IEnumerable<CustomerBO> GetAllCustomers()
     {
          return Map(DBContext.Customers.Select(c => Map(c));
     }

     private CustomerBO Map(CustomerEntity entity)
     {
          CustomerBo bo = new CustomerBO();
          bo.FirstName = entity.FirstName;
          //etc
          bo.InvoicesNumber = entity.invoices.Count();
          bo.InvoicesTotalAmount = entity.invoices.select(i => i.Amount).Sum();
     }


}
```

You may think, this seems slow, but do not be tempted by the siren of premature optimization. Also, if you are very concerned about speed, you should use Dapper.net instead of entity framework.

You then call the repository from your controller, and map the BO to the view model in the controller, or just use the BO directly if it suits your purposes.

There is still coupling inside the repository, but it is limited to only there, so if you need to change your DB, you only have to change it one place

Comment: That's funny, I ended up with a similar solution, but with DI to allow unit testing. And I totally agree with your statement about CustomerBO  not having any references to EF and Dapper; but speed is not at all a priority :)

Comment: btw, if you want to get very pedantic, the repository should not do the summing... that is considered business logic and should be handled by CustomerBO or an InvoiceCollection class

Comment: Yes, but it was just an simplified exemple, not real code nor an exactly real situation ;)